# Code to submit data from login page to MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a simple HTML Login page.
I have created a PHP file to transfer data to MySQL database(Using MySQL workbench 8.0)
However, when I click submit, a page  just open with some code from my PHP file and no data is transferred to my database.
How can I transfer data from my Login page to my MYSQL database?

I have saved my PHP file in the C://

Code for Login Page:

```
<html>
   <head>
         <title>Login</title>
  </head>
   <body>
       <form action="/Test1.php">
        Username:<br>
        <input type="text" value="username"><br>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="text" value="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

CODE for PHP:

```
<html>
<? php
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');
if (!empty($username)){
if (!empty($password)){
    $host = "localhost:3306";
    $dbusername = "root";
    $dbpassword = "";
    $dbname = "login";

    // Create Connection
    $conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
    if (mysql_connect_error()){
        die ( 'Connect Error ('.mysqli_connect_errno().')'.mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO login.user (username, password)
        values ('$username', '$password')";
        if ($conn->query($sql)){
            echo "New record is inserted successfully";
        }
        else {
            echo "Error:".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
        }
        $conn->close();
}
}
else { 
echo "Password should not be empty";
die ();
}

else {
    echo "Username should not be empty";
    die();
}

?>
</html>
```

I expect data from HTML file to be inputed in MYSQL Database but instead a new page open up with this:

```
query($sql)){ echo "New record is inserted successfully"; } else { echo "Error:".$sql."
".$conn->error; } $conn->close(); } } else { echo "Password should not be empty"; die (); } else { echo "Username should not be empty"; die(); } ?>
```

Comment: '<? php' - there shouldn't be a space between

Comment: Thanks. But same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: The main problem is that you are not calling file from the web server or the extension of file may not be `.php`

Comment: See screenshot when file have `.html` extension and compare your output https://imgur.com/FW395Q3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```php
<html>
<?php
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');

if (empty($username)) {
    echo 'Username should not be empty';
    exit;
}
if (empty($password)) {
    echo 'Password should not be empty';
    exit;
}

$host = 'localhost:3306';
$dbusername = '';
$dbpassword = '';
$dbname = '';

// Create Connection
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

try {
    $connection = new mysqli($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    exit('Error connecting to database');
}
$connection->set_charset('utf8mb4');

try {
    $statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO login.user (username, password) values (?, ?)");
    $statement->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->close();

    echo 'New record is inserted successfully';
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $exception->getMessage();
}

$connection->close();

?>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not `exit` in your code unnecessarily. There is no need to catch the exceptions, because you don't do anything with them.

Comment: @Dharman This is just a demo and a database password. It makes no sense to store a hashed database password, because a hash cannot be "unhashed".

Comment: That is the whole point. Never store passwords in clear text. Even if just for a demo.